# C++ Randomly generate Multiples of 16

Tags: c++

Is it possible to generate random multiples of a specific number in C++? 
Let's say I want to generate multiples of 16 and only 16, how would this be done?

Comment: Generate random value and multiply by 16 . Honestly all the words needed to answer that are present *in your question*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Randomly generate a number and multiply it with 16.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<random>` header (`C++11`) to generate random numbers:

```
int get_random()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 20); // range 1 - 20
    return dis(gen);
}
```

And multiply with `16`:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums;
    for (int i{}; i != 5; ++i)
        nums.emplace_back(get_random() * 16);
}
```